# Multiple cursor - is possible this?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I have this structure

```
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

The desired output is the

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Is it possibble with multiple cursor and some shortcut?

Do not overwrite each line separately.

Thank you

(With Emmet plugin its easy, but only when prepare new structure, structure is already defined above)

Comment: Are you using a programming language? What does this have to do with sublimetext?

Comment: yes I use PHP, but this is not a question of the programming language, but the ability sublime text or "smarts" you know.

This is a very common question on the general code, but in the real example I can edit CSS or other code fragments.

Comment: you have to show your code that gives the output you have written, and you should tell us in the question that you are using php

Comment: Again, this is pure HTML fragment, PHP doesnt related with it.

The question is how to do it in the editor SUBLIME TEXT 2 with multiple cursor or some existing plugin.

For better idea look -> https://www.sublimetext.com/  first slide ...

Comment: I see. You want sublime text to automatically update those div's with iterated content? Then I cannot help you.

Comment: Im using EMMET (new version of ZenCoding + Multiple Cursors, this works fine when build new structure, but editing existing is problem. Thx for your time.

Comment: this may be the solution http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11376

Answer (score 3):

Think this plugin will do what you want

https://bitbucket.org/markstahler/insert-nums

Available through package control. Search for "Insert Nums"

Another plugin that will do what you want I believe.

https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry

Answer (score -1):

on a mac, you can CMD + click mouse pointer to each place, you will have multiple cursors, but then you edit all instances at once == the same number

Comment: This answer doesn't do what the OP wants.